# http.get problems angular + nodejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, http

When i use this code, work and i get tem response "ok":

controller.js

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('AppController',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){

    $http.get('/').
        success(function (response) {
        console.log("ok");
    });

}]);
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.get('/', function (req, res){

    var person1 = {
        name: 'Tim',
        email:'tim@gmail.com',
        number:'32232233'
    };

    var person2 = {
        name :'Dani',
        email:'Dani@gmail.com',
        number:'22222222'
    };

    var contactList = [person1,person2];

    res.json = contactList;
    console.log("send work");
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log("Server running on port 3000");
```

but, when i change `$http.get('/')` to `$http.get('/list')` and `app.get('/', function (req, res)` to `app.get('/list', function (req, res)` not works.

The get time 'list' stay **Pending** for ever, and when i stop node server i get "GET http://localhost:3000/list net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE".

Comment: res.json(contactList);

Answer (score 2):

You aren't actually calling the `res.json()` method.

Make sure you are actually invoking the method rather than assigning it to equal the contact list:

```
res.json(contactList);
```

vs.

```
res.json = contactList
```

In context:

```
app.get('/list', function (req, res){

    var person1 = {
        name: 'Tim',
        email:'tim@gmail.com',
        number:'32232233'
    };

    var person2 = {
        name :'Dani',
        email:'Dani@gmail.com',
        number:'22222222'
    };

    var contactList = [person1,person2];

    res.json(contactList);
    console.log("send work");
});
```

The reason you are probably getting a response on '/' is because your app is hosted on '/', so you are going to get a response.